# read & write vcard using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vcf-vcard

i am trying to create & read both for vcard, after googleng for a while not getting a proper example of  it, is there any vcard creator/ reader to start ,

i am trying this https://www.npmjs.org/package/vcard

my code to it

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    //https://github.com/Fusselwurm/vcard-js/commit/dafd17ffd226c6170849be82e9c5dae94e23b8f0
    card.readFile("./public/sample.vcf", function(err, json1) {
        if(err){  
            console.log("vcard err "+err);
            res.json(util.inspect(json1));
            }
        else
            {
            console.log("vcard json "+json1);
            console.log("vcard json "+util.inspect(json1));
            res.json(util.inspect(json1));
            }


    });
});
```

sample.vcf file

> BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0 N:Gump;Forrest;;Mr. FN:Forrest Gump ORG:Bubba
>   Gump Shrimp Co. TITLE:Shrimp Man TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
>   PHOTO;VALUE=URL;TYPE=GIF:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
>   TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-12121 ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters
>   Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America LABEL;TYPE=WORK:100
>   Waters Edge\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
>   ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of
>   America LABEL;TYPE=HOME:42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited
>   States of America EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
>   REV:2008-04-24T19:52:43Z END:VCARD BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:3.0
>   N:Gump;Forrest;;Mr. FN:Forrest Gump ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
>   TITLE:Shrimp Man TEL;TYPE=HOME,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
>   PHOTO;VALUE=URL;TYPE=GIF:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
>   TEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:(111) 555-12121 ADR;TYPE=WORK:;;100 Waters
>   Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America LABEL;TYPE=WORK:100
>   Waters Edge\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America
>   ADR;TYPE=HOME:;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of
>   America LABEL;TYPE=HOME:42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited
>   States of America EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:forrestgump@example.com
>   REV:2008-04-24T19:52:43Z END:VCARD

logcat output:
it works for only 1 vcard data in sample.vcf, but when it contains more data then it throughs error
i.e
Invalid vCard data: One or more required elements are missing (VERSION and FN)

Answer (score 4):

I think there's a couple of issues here:

1. The vcard library you're using is unfinished
2. The vcard your're using is not formatted properly

Have a look at `vcardparser` library instead.

```
var vcardparser = require('vcardparser');

vcardparser.parseFile("./sample.vcf", function(err, json) {
    if(err)
        return console.log(err);
    console.log(json);
});
```

Here's a sample vcard:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:4.0
N:Gump;Forrest;;;
FN:Forrest Gump
ORG:Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.
TITLE:Shrimp Man
PHOTO;MEDIATYPE=image/gif:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-111-555-1212
TEL;TYPE=home,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+1-404-555-1212
ADR;TYPE=work;LABEL="100 Waters Edge\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America"
  :;;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
ADR;TYPE=home;LABEL="42 Plantation St.\nBaytown, LA 30314\nUnited States of America"
 :;;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America
EMAIL:forrestgump@example.com
REV:20080424T195243Z
END:VCARD
```

And the output from `vcardparser`

```
{ begin: 'VCARD',
  version: '4.0',
  n:
   { last: 'Gump',
     first: 'Forrest',
     middle: '',
     prefix: '',
     suffix: '' },
  fn: 'Forrest Gump',
  org: { name: 'Bubba Gump Shrimp Co.', dept: undefined },
  title: 'Shrimp Man',
  photo:
   { type: [],
     value: 'http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif' },
  tel:
   [ { type: [Object], value: 'tel:+1-111-555-1212' },
     { type: [Object],
       value: 'tel:+1-404-555-1212ADR;TYPE=work;LABEL="100 Waters Edge\\nBaytown, LA 30314\\nUnited States of America"' } ],
  '  ': ';;100 Waters Edge;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of AmericaADR;TYPE=home;LABEL="42 Plantation St.\\nBaytown, LA 30314\\nUnited States of America"',
  ' ': ';;42 Plantation St.;Baytown;LA;30314;United States of America',
  email: [ { type: [], value: 'forrestgump@example.com' } ],
  rev: '20080424T195243Z',
  end: 'VCARD' }
```

Comment: i will try this & let you know